# Run piped commands with eval

Tags: bash, escaping, pipe, eval, quoting

I have the following command line to check free space of a file system:

```
fs_used=`df -h /u01 | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d'%' -f1`
```

It works fine.  It returns the percentage of the used space on the file system (without the % symbol).

**Now I need to make it variable and run it with the eval command**.  I tried the following but it doesn't work (exit with df: invalid option -- 'd')

```
df_cmnd="df -h $fs1 | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d'%' -f1"
fs_used=eval $df_cmnd
```

The problem, I guess, is that eval cannot run piped commands.  Is that true?
is there any workaround or alternative to make this code run?

Comment: No, you need to make it a *function*, not a variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Backslash-escape the `$`, and use `$()`:

```
#              V                                         V
df_cmnd="df -h \$fs1 | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print \$4}' | cut -d'%' -f1"
fs_used=$(eval "$df_cmnd")
#       ^^               ^
```

This will use the value of `fs1` at the time you eval.

But, in reality, please [don't use eval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/2877364)!  Make it a shell function instead:

```
df_cmnd(){
    df -h "$1" | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d'%' -f1
}
fs_used=$(df_cmnd /u01)
```

Then you don't have to worry about escaping.

#### Explanation

Look at how `bash` interprets your `df_cmnd` assignment:

```
$ df_cmnd="df -h $fs1 | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d'%' -f1"
$ echo $df_cmnd
df -h | sed '1d' | sed '1d' | awk '{print }' | cut -d'%' -f1
#    ^                                   ^
```

In my case, `fs1` was empty, so I just got `df -h` for the `df` part.  In your case and mine, bash replaced `$4` with its value, here, empty since I wasn't running in a script with four arguments.  Therefore, awk will print the whole line rather than just the fourth field.

Comment: Thank alot, I am going with the function option

Comment: @OuldAbba I am delighted to hear it! :D :D :D  Less `eval` makes the world a better place.

Comment: And if you do ever use `eval`, remember to double-quote your variables (e.g. `eval "$df_cmnd"`). This eliminates one whole class of weird `eval`-related bugs. (Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the other dozen or so classes of weird `eval`-related bugs. So you should still avoid `eval`.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good point - edited.  Although I have mixed feelings about showing how to use `eval` "properly" ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had a legitimate need for `eval`-ing a string: a helper scripts runs a complicated sequence of pipes with double-quoting (e.g. `--json-override='"key": "value"'`), 460+ characters long. But when I run it with `--noop`, I want to see the command that would be executed, in a copy-pasteable form for manual execution. I came up with this:

```
echo_eval () {
    cmd=$(cat)
    if ((noop)); then
        echo "$cmd"
    else
        eval "$cmd"
    fi
}

foo () { for arg; do echo "[$arg]"; done; }

echo_eval <<EOF
foo 1 2 "3 4" '"5 6"' " 7 " "\"8 9\"" | tac
EOF
exit 1
```

The main purpose of the here-document is to skip all the pitfalls of using the ' and " quotes in an already ' or "-quoted string (pain and suffering).

While I haven't tested it extensively, it seems to hit the relevant check-boxes, like pipes, quoting, quoting space-containing arguments, preserving quoted quotes, escaped quotes, leading/trailing space in arguments, etc.:

```
["8 9"]
[ 7 ]
["5 6"]
[3 4]
[2]
[1]
```

When `noop` is true, I get:

```
foo 1 "2" "3 4" '"5 6"' " 7 " "\"8 9\"" | tac
```

which is the command verbatim, copy-pasteable for manual execution and yielding the same output.

We can also use `<<'EOF'` to disable substitution of any `$`s before `echo_eval`, but if any variable/command substitution does need to happen before calling `echo_eval`, we have to use `<<EOF` and escape all `$`s that shouldn't be evaluated before.

---

Having said all this, I'd gladly (a) hear if there are pitfalls (apart from the `$` mentioned above) and (b) see a better solution to the problem if there is one.